# How to organize routes for user and admin in angular separately

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am working on an Angular & Node app. My all view files are stored in public and I created a middleware to access the static file as below:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname+ "/public"));
```

Now, When I run my app,`localhost://3000/#/`,  first of all `index.html` file is executing where only header and footer are placed and then the `ng-view` part.

Now I want to know, where I have to place my `admin` html files so that I can access the url like as `localhost://3000/#/admin/dashboard`.

Even `User` view layout is different from `admin`layout.

How to organize `user` `admin` view files and their routes?

Answer (score 0):

first create a admin.view.html file in (public/views). Then call the admin.view.html to the app.js inside the same folder public (like this way in app.js)

```
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
  when('/admin', {
    templateUrl: 'views/admin.view.html',
    controller: 'AdminCtrl'
  })
```

After that make a new folder(controller) in same folder public and make a file admin.controller.js. and then come out of folder and in the routes folder make a file admin.js.                                        if you got from this its good or just give your emailid i wil mail you a project made by me on angular and node which will may help you

Comment: You can send me on sharmasaurabh450@gmail.com so that I can get the solution.

Comment: As you mentioned above, if I will use this then it will use Theme layout of Normal user. but I have different Theme Layout for Admin.

Comment: the new one which i suggested did not  work for you.

Comment: sending project it is jsut a artcile add update delete project in angular.

Comment: whats the problem now.

Comment: should i email you the project which is simple add,update delete article made in angular js

Comment: check your mail

Comment: I didn't get any mail... can u plz resend that

Answer (score 0):

Basically, with the application like that, you must have something called "permission" on each URL.

But for the specific case like you mentioned above. You can use ng-if condition directive to show which you want to show in each view (admin/user).

You do not need to separate user.html file and admin.html file.
You just need an index.html with the layout inside it. (Admin or user must have the same layout page right?). You should separate this view to multiple angular module (menu bar, tabs, toolbar ...) and use ng-if to show which you want to show.

Comment: it will be a long process. and I don't want to do with that.

Comment: Yeah! I know that, the rest of my answer was mentioned `ng-if` directive, you can use it to separate the view :D

Comment: You mean, with the same URL, admin and user has different view, right ?

Comment: Yes right...with same url user and admin has different view. Suppose in User view I have header, footer and a sidebar. and in admin I have only header.... so Now I want to call admin layout view when I access admin url and user layout should be call when access user url.

Comment: What you need to hide or show in each case, you can wrap it into an directive or module. In your case, you will have header directive, footer directive. You have the index.html file that contains all layout with all 2 directives.In case of admin, you show the view with just header by hiding the footer view and in case of user you show all the layout.

Comment: Is there any way like we create middleware for folder `app.use(express.static(__dirname+ "/public"));` . same can we do it like as ? `app.use(express.static(__dirname+ "/public/admin"));`

Comment: My answer for the SPA app, sorry for misunderstanding. By your case, I think this post is fit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32032561/different-views-routes-by-the-type-of-user-in-express-js

Answer (score 0):

to call admin layout you should this hope this will work for you

```
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
  when('/admin', {
     url: '/admin',
        templateUrl: 'views/admin/layout.html'

  }).
when('admin.login', {
        url: '/admin/login',
        templateUrl: 'views/admin/login.html',
        controller: 'AdminLoginCtrl'
    })
```

Then you need to create this new Layout Pages. On: views/admin/layout.html

```
<div>
    <ui-view/>
</div>
```

and similars for others...

Comment: My all user html files are placed in `public` folder... so you mean, I have to place user layout files in to `public>user` folder... right?

Comment: and admin html files  in `public>admin` as well